# Find $x$ for which $\int_1^2 \frac{e^{-t}}{1+xt} dt$ is continuous and differentiable.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Find $x \in \mathbb{R}$ for which $$f(x)=\int_1^2 \frac{e^{-t}}{1+xt} dt$$ is continuous and differentiable. And if possible, find this function and the derivative of this function in the closed form.

For $x \ge 0$,

we have $\frac{e^{-t}}{1+xt} \le e^{-t}$ and $\int_1^2 e^{-t} dt$ converges. So $f(x)$ is continuous on $[0, \infty)$.

In the case of the derivative,

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}\frac{e^{-t}}{1+xt}=-\frac{te^{-t}}{(1+xt)^2}$$

and again, for $x \ge 0$, $$\Biggr|-\frac{te^{-t}}{(1+xt)^2}\Biggl| \le te^{-t}$$

$$\int_1^2 te^{-t} dt = \frac{2}{e} - \frac{3}{e^2}$$

So $$f'(x)= \int_1^2 -\frac{t e^{-t}}{(1+xt)^2} dt$$
is differentiable on $x \in [0, \infty)$.

Also, if $x \in [-1, -\frac{1}{2}]$, then $$\lim_{t \to -\frac{1}{x}} \frac{e^{-t}}{1+xt} = \text{NOT defined}.$$

So $f(x)$ cannot be defined for $x \in [-1, -\frac{1}{2}]$. But I'm not sure whether this interval is only exception or not.

Here are my questions regarding the above function.

> I'm not sure how to deal with $x <0$, is this function continous and differentiable for all $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus [-1, -\frac{1}{2}]$?

> Also, I'd like to calculate the function or the derivative of the function in closed forms, if possible.

Thank you, in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the same reasoning as you did for $x\ge0,$ $f$ is smooth as soon as $1+xt$ never vanishes for $t\in[1,2],$ i.e. as soon as $x<-1$ or $x>-1/2.$ This is essentially because for such an $x$, $$\forall t\in[1,2]\quad|1+xt|\ge\epsilon$$
for some positive $\epsilon$ easily computable from $x.$

On the other hand, for $x\in[-1,-1/2],$ $f$ is not even defined, essentially because $s\mapsto1/s$ is not integrable at $0$ (which is worse than having no finite limit).

I have no idea for a closed form.

Answer (score 2):

Now, we will get a close form for $f(x)\,.$

It is obvious that $\,f(0)=\displaystyle\!\!\int_1^2\!\frac{e^{-t}}{1+0t}\,\mathrm dt=e^{-1}-e^{-2}=\dfrac{e-1}{e^2}\,.$

For any $\,x\in\Bbb R\setminus\left(\left[-1,-\dfrac12\right]\bigcup\big\{0\big\}\right)$ it results that

$\begin{align}f(x)&=\displaystyle\!\!\int_1^2\!\frac{e^{-t}}{1+xt}\,\mathrm dt\!\underset{\overbrace{\;u=t+\frac 1x\;}}{=}\int_{1+\frac1x}^{2+\frac1x}\dfrac{e^{\frac1x-u}}{xu}\,\mathrm du=\\[3pt]&=\dfrac1xe^{\frac1x}\!\int_{1+\frac1x}^{2+\frac1x}\!\dfrac{e^{-u}}u\,\mathrm du=\\[3pt]&=\dfrac1xe^{\frac1x}\left[-\int_{2+\frac1x}^{+\infty}\dfrac{e^{-u}}u\,\mathrm du+\int_{1+\frac1x}^{+\infty}\dfrac{e^{-u}}u\,\mathrm du\right]=\\[3pt]&=\dfrac1xe^{\frac1x}\left[\mathrm{Ei}\left(-2-\dfrac1x\right)-\mathrm{Ei}\left(-1-\dfrac1x\right)\right]\end{align}$

where $\,\mathrm{Ei}(z)\,$ is the exponential integral.

$\mathrm{Ei}(z)=-\displaystyle\int_{-z}^{+\infty}\dfrac{e^{-u}}u\,\mathrm du\;\;\;$ for any $\,z\in\Bbb R\,\land\,z\neq0\,.$

The definition above is also used for positive values of $\,z\,$ and in that case the integral has to be understood in terms of the Cauchy principal value due to the singularity of the integrand at zero.

Comment: It is better to use the well-behaved function $E_1(z)$ (cf. [$(6.2.1)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/6.2.E1)).